# Prevent Duplicate content when using CloudFlare

Tags: robots.txt, duplicate-content, googlebot, web-crawlers, cloudflare

I have a website which uses CloudFlare CDN. At the CDN setup, CloudFlare created a sub-domain like direct.example.com to my website, which can be used to override CloudFlare and access the site directly.

When I do a google search for "site:direct.example.com" it comes up with results. It means google had also crawled and indexed that sub-domain too. The problem is, since example.com & direct.example.com both consists of same content, it will end up in a content duplication. (I think it's not good for SEO).

So what I want is google bot to **not to crawl and index** "direct.example.com". I tried to use robots.txt to do the trick, but I failed since both uses the same robots.txt. What should I do to entirely prevent my sub-domain from Indexing? Is there any other options to over come this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: What type of content is being indexed?

Comment: Do you use the direct subdomain? If not, you could just disable it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to disable the 'direct' subdomain. If however you want to use that subdomain you would have to use a more creative approach.

One way to do it is to have a dynamic robots.txt. When the web spider requests robots.txt we redirect it to our dynamic robots page. If the subdomain matches our criteria we send a 'disallow' otherwise we just present the normal robots.txt.

If you use Apache your rewrite rule might look something like this:

```
RewriteRule /robots\.txt$ /var/www/myweb/robots.php
```

The php file is generic.

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: text/plain');

    if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'direct.example.com') { 
        echo "User-agent: *\n";
        echo "Disallow: /\n";
    } else {              
        include('robots.txt');    
    }
```